# CAML query to get all items which are modified or created today?

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, caml

Can anyone help me with CAML query where items are created or modified today.

Trying below where I am excluding one specific item and getting modified item today but its not working:

```
<View><Query><Where><And><Neq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Counter'>412</Value></Neq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Modified' /><Value Type='DateTime'><Today/></Value></Eq></Neq></And></Where></Query><RowLimit>500</RowLimit></View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this CAML query:

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <And>
                <Neq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Counter'>412</Value></Neq>
                <Or>
                    <Eq><FieldRef Name='Modified' /><Value Type='DateTime'><Today/></Value></Eq>
                    <Eq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value Type='DateTime'><Today/></Value></Eq>
                </Or>
            </And>
        </Where>
    </Query>
    <RowLimit>500</RowLimit>
</View>
```

**Documentation**: [Query schema in CAML](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/query-schema)